# ERROR: the certificate of ‘releases.hashicorp.com’ is not trusted

Tags: docker

When I’m trying to build docker image out of docker file, i need to install terrraform dependence. When I’m trying to download terraform dependency, I’m getting the above error

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and the output of `docker build`?